# Can I make trivial edits to my question after I choose an answer?

Tags: support, edits

Say I have asked a question and it was answered, but it had an untrue statement in it. No, I didn't realize that it was untrue later; I knew it was untrue while writing it, but I didn't mind much. I chose an answer. After some time, I decide to edit the statement (e.g. I lied about how sure I was about something by saying "I am sure something is true", and I want to change it to "Later edit: I wasn't sure actually").

Since my question asks for a particular thing, and editing this statement won't change what my question asks for (it may only affect it a little), am I allowed to edit it? The answer will still be satisfying enough, the question will just be changed a little, but not significantly.
Of course, I'll also write that the change is a later edit.

Comment: It sounds like that sentence is simply *irrelevant* to the question.  Based on your description you should just remove it, not change it.  How sure you are of some thing isn't really relevant to the question.

Comment: Regardless, why post here *after* making the edit, if you're not sure it's appropriate to make it?  If you want to know if the edit is appropriate you should ask *before* making the edit.

Comment: Whether you make this edit or not, you should never be pointing them out as "later edit" or as any edit at all. That's what revision history is for. Write the question the way it should be written.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your edits don't fundamentally change the question being asked or, worse, make existing answers completely invalid, it's perfectly fine to edit your question, *especially* if it makes it easier to read or provides more clarity. Remember: The answers you receive ideally don't benefit only you, but benefit people who come along later who have the same question.

There's more in the Help Center:

- [Why can people edit my posts? How does editing work?](/help/editing)
- [Edit questions and answers](/help/privileges/edit)

Comment: Is there something the website's rules say about this as well? (About making such edits that I'm speaking of)

Comment: Its kinda common sense and civility. Personally, I think moving the goalposts dosen't seem fair.

Comment: Can someone like a moderator or someone who's in charge verify that I can make the edits I ask about? Does a rule allow it? I just want to be sure, sorry if I unfairly treat anyone here as dishonest, I don't intend this.

Comment: Is the Help Center authoritative enough for you? https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/editing

Comment: Thank you, yes it is.